# How to create a numpy matrix with differing column data types?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lets say I have three vectors `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([1.2, 3.2, 4.5])
c = np.array([True, True, False])
```

What is the simplest way to turn this into a matrix `d` of differing data types and column labels, as such:

```
d = ([[1, 1.2, True],
     [2, 3.2, True], 
     [3, 4.5, False]], 
     dtype=[('aVals','i8'), ('bVals','f4'), ('cVals','bool')])
```

So that I can then save this matrix to a `.npy` file and access the data as such after opening it;

```
>>> d = np.load('dFile')
>>> d['aVals']
np.array([1,2,3], dtype = [('aVals', '<i8)])
```

I have used a cimple `column_stack` to create the matrix, but I am getting a headache trying to figure out how to include the datatypes and column names, since `column_stack` does not accept a `dtype` argument, and I can't see a way to add field names and data types after the `column_stack` is preformed. It is worth mentioning that the vectors `a`, `b`, and `c` have no explicit datatypes declared upon their creation, they are as shown above.

Comment: By the way, if you are doing this simply to save the arrays, you could use `np.savez(outfile, aVals=a, bVals=b, cVals=c)` to save all three arrays to a compressed npz file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a little known `recarray` function that constructs arrays like this.  It was cited in a recent SO question:

[Assigning field names to numpy array in Python 2.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32474115/assigning-field-names-to-numpy-array-in-python-2-7-3)

Allowing it to deduce everything from the input arrays:

```
In [19]: np.rec.fromarrays([a,b,c])
Out[19]: 
rec.array([(1, 1.2, True), (2, 3.2, True), (3, 4.5, False)], 
          dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '?')])
```

Specifying names

```
In [26]: d=np.rec.fromarrays([a,b,c],names=['avals','bvals','cVals'])
In [27]: d
Out[27]: 
rec.array([(1, 1.2, True), 
           (2, 3.2, True), 
           (3, 4.5, False)], 
          dtype=[('avals', '<i4'), ('bvals', '<f8'), ('cVals', '?')])
In [28]: d['cVals']
Out[28]: array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

After creating the target array of right size and dtype it does a field by field copy.  This is typical of the `rec.recfunctions` (even `astype` does this).

```
# populate the record array (makes a copy)
for i in range(len(arrayList)):
    _array[_names[i]] = arrayList[i]
```

A 2011 reference: [How to make a Structured Array from multiple simple array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220689/how-to-make-a-structured-array-from-multiple-simple-array)

Comment: to add to hpaulj comment there is another simple way.... from numpy.lib._iotools import easy_dtype as easy ... easy((int, float, float), names="a,b,c") ... yields a dtype of  ....  dtype([('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8')])

Comment: `easy_dtype` is used by `genfromtxt` to translate the `dtype` parameter into the more formal `dtype`.    `fromarrays` uses `np.rec.format_parser` to do this translation.

Comment: Thank you this is perfect, and very simple

Answer (score 3):

```
d = np.empty(len(a), dtype=[('aVals',a.dtype), ('bVals',b.dtype), ('cVals',c.dtype)])
d['aVals'] = a
d['bVals'] = b
d['cVals'] = c
```

As a reusable function:

```
def column_stack_overflow(**kwargs):
    dtype = [(name, val.dtype) for name, val in kwargs.items()]
    arr = np.empty(len(kwargs.values()[0]), dtype=dtype)
    for name, val in kwargs.items():
        arr[name] = val
    return arr
```

Then:

```
column_stack_overflow(aVals=a, bVals=b, cVals=c)
```

But note kwargs is a dict so unordered, so you might not get the columns in the order you pass them.